# Map<String, list<AddressBook>> want to iterate over map with key and find-out how many objects are there in the list. I have value as list of objects

Tags: java, java-8

```java
cityContactMap.computeIfAbsent(cityName,cityName -> new ArrayList<>())
    .add(new AddressBook(
        last_Name, first_Name, address, cityName, stateName, phone_Number, zip_Code, email
    ));
    
public void displayCity() {
    System.out.println("Enter  City name  \n");
    String cityNameFilter = sc.next();  
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

    objectList = stateContactMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(cityNameFilter))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  
    int num = objectList.size();
    System.out.println("List of city objects :"+objectList);
}
```

MY output is like this List of city objects:

> `[1=[First Name :1 Last Name :1 Address :1  City :1 State : 1 Zip_Code :1.0 Phone : 1.0 Email :1, First Name :1 Last Name :1 Address :1  City :1 State : 1 Zip_Code :1.0 Phone : 1.0 Email :1]]`

Trying to iterate over map and play with list of objects.

When I do `Objectlist.size()` or `Objectlist.stream.count()` I am getting 1 as output.

Comment: If you already know the key and filter by it anyway and all you want to know is how many objects there are in your list for that key, all you need is a simple `stateContactMap.get(cityNameFilter).size();`, or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: provide us what output you expect. your statement wasn't clear. need more information what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you want to be safe against non-existing keys, just use `stateContactMap.getOrDefault(cityNameFilter, Collections.emptyList()).size()`. There’s no point in doing a Stream operation. But well, if you stream over an `entrySet()` and accept only one key value, the number of resulting entries will be zero or one. That’s expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I hope this will answer your query.**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cityToSearch = "city1";
        getAddressBasedOnCity(cityToSearch);
    }

    private static void getAddressBasedOnCity(String cityToSearch) {
        Map<String, List<AddressBook>> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        data.put("city1", Arrays.asList(
                new AddressBook("f1","l1","add1","city1","state1",123456),
                new AddressBook("f2","l2","add2","city2","state2",123457),
                new AddressBook("f3","l3","add3","city3","state3",123458),
                new AddressBook("f4","l4","add4","city4","state4",123459)));
        data.put("city2", Arrays.asList(
                new AddressBook("f1","l1","add1","city1","state1",123456),
                new AddressBook("f2","l2","add2","city2","state2",123457)));

        List<AddressBook> filteredData = data.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .filter(x -> x.getCity().equals(cityToSearch)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("AddressData:: " + filteredData);
        System.out.println("AddressData count:: " + filteredData.size());
    }
}
```

**AddressBook.java**

```
public class AddressBook {

    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private long zipCode;

    public AddressBook(String fName, String lName, String address, String city, String state, long zipCode) {
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public long getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(long zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AddressBook{" +
                "fName='" + fName + '\'' +
                ", lName='" + lName + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", state='" + state + '\'' +
                ", zipCode=" + zipCode +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
AddressData:: [AddressBook{fName='f1', lName='l1', address='add1', city='city1', state='state1', zipCode=123456}, AddressBook{fName='f1', lName='l1', address='add1', city='city1', state='state1', zipCode=123456}]
AddressData count:: 2
```

**Thanks**
*Girdhar*

Answer (score 0):

I used flat map to access a list of objects which was my value on the map.

```
objectList = cityContactMap.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(cityNameFilter))
      .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thank you for your responses. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you trying to find the most expensive way for you operation? Then, you are close to it, but there’s a tiny thing you could make worse…